# Positioning drop down in panel heading boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add drop down to panel header (bootstrap). I've aligned drop down to right but it's not positioning properly.

**Code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>
                    Analytics
                </h3>
                <div class="btn-group" style="float: right;">
                    <button class="btn">Action</button>
                    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item I</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item II</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item III</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="analytics-chart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                    
 </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open bootstrap dropdown-toggle to the left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738449/open-bootstrap-dropdown-toggle-to-the-left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do in this situation is move the `btn-group` inside of the `<h3>` tag before applying the `float:right;` style (either using `style="float:right;"` or `class="pull-right"`). Then, simply adjust the top margin to something that makes it fit a little better into the `panel-title`, such as `-8px`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>
          <div class="btn-group pull-right" style="margin-top:-8px;">
            <button class="btn">Action</button>
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a href="#">Item I</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item II</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item III</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          Analytics
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="analytics-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>                    
</div>
```

Also, remember to add `dropdown-menu-right` to your dropdown when using `pull-right`, otherwise it will extend beyond the edge of the screen.

Buttons never behave well when added to a `panel-heading` class, but you're free to tweak the classes to fit your needs.

Hope this helps!

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/QU85henAnV)